# Simple Angular app - cannot get $http success/then to fire

Tags: angularjs

```
angular.module('alertApp', [
    'alertApp.controllers',
    'alertApp.services'
]);
```

---

```
angular.module('alertApp.services', []).
factory('alertAPIservice', function($http) {

var alertAPI = {};

alertAPI.getAlerts = function() {
  return $http({
    method: 'JSONP', 
    url: 'http://localhost:50828/api/alert'
  });
}
 return alertAPI;
});
```

---

```
angular.module('alertApp.controllers', [])
.controller('mainController', function($scope, alertAPIservice) {
    $scope.message = 'Hello Mid-World!';
    $scope.alertsList = [];

    alertAPIservice.getAlerts().success(function (response) {
        $scope.alertsList = response;
    });  

});
```

My app runs fine without errors and I can see the $scope.message displayed on the page. In fiddler I can see that my api call returns a 200 message, but the success function is never called. What have I done wrong

**UPDATE**

I Changed to:

```
alertAPIservice.getAlerts().then(function successCallback(response) {
     $scope.alertsList = response;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
   console.log("turd");
  });
```

And although I receieve a 200 in fiddler, the error callback is called. The response is from web api and is of type Ok();

Comment: `200` doesn't necessarily mean success. Add an error handler.

Comment: Thanks just saw your comment, I was busy adding an error handler :)

Comment: What are the first, say, 8 characters in the response body?

Comment: There's your problem, that's JSON, not JSON**P**. There should have been a syntax error in your console with this.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll do some reading.

Comment: Thanks, I used the EnableCors atribute on my controller and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the name of the callback as **"JSON_CALLBACK"**.

Please refer your updated code as below -

```js
angular.module('alertApp', ['alertApp.controllers','alertApp.services']);

angular.module('alertApp.services', []).factory('alertAPIservice', function($http) {
var alertAPI = {};
alertAPI.getAlerts = function() {
  return $http.jsonp('https://angularjs.org/greet.php?name=StackOverflow&callback=JSON_CALLBACK');
  //use &callback=JSON_CALLBACK' in url
}
 return alertAPI;
});

angular.module('alertApp.controllers', [])
.controller('mainController', function($scope, alertAPIservice) {
    $scope.message = 'Hello Mid-World!';
    $scope.alertsList = "loading data";

    alertAPIservice.getAlerts().then(function (response) {
        $scope.alertsList = response.data;
    },function(error,a,b){
        $scope.alertsList = error;
    });  

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="alertApp">
<div ng-controller="mainController">
  {{message}}

  <div>
    <pre>{{alertsList|json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

you can refer jsonp documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#jsonp).

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one ('then' instead of 'success' ):

`alertAPIservice.getAlerts().then(function (response) {
        $scope.alertsList = response;
 });`

Comment: Thanks. I did read it was better to use then, but this doesn't work either. I have no console messages and can again see a 200 result from my web api call